# Access to Spring Boot Application logs

Tags: spring-boot, rest, docker, logging, openshift

Is there a way to access the Spring Boot Application **logs through the REST** webservice? I am running my Spring Boot microservices in Openshift, but dont have access to the Admin console, so I am wondering, if I can easily access the logs or copy them per demand somewhere.

I'm not interested in advices such configure ELK, etc, because I am not the owner of the infrastructure, just the microservices.

Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is an out-the-box endpoint for that. But if you had to it, you might wanna store logs in a file, and then expose an endpoint which returns the content of that file

Comment: Thanks @Elfarni. Yes, thats exactly what I did, and its working. I was just wondering, if there is some actuator for this or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved as follows. Store the logs into the file, connect microservice to SBA and check the logs there.

```
logging:  
   file: /log/application.log
```

And then use Spring Boot Admin, which allows you to see the logs. Hope it helps somebody.